# After brew upgrade can't load bin/rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on rails5 project. Accidentally I typed `brew upgrade` (I supposed to uninstall imagemagick then install)

`bin/rails c` command is not working now.

**enviroment**:

- Mac os 10.12
- ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029)
  [x86_64-darwin16]
- Rails 5.1.6.1  , using gem 'mysql2', '0.4.10'

I tryed:

1. `brew link readline --force`
2. `ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib`
3. `brew info readline`
    
   readline: stable 8.0.0 (bottled) [keg-only]
   Library for command-line editing
   /usr/local/Cellar/readline/8.0.0 (49 files, 1.5MB) *
   Poured from bottle on 2019-02-15 at 17:16:19

but both still nothing changes, checked `mysql.server start` and it gives `Starting MySQL.......... SUCCESS!`

Also, checked `mysql --version`, got `mysql  Ver 8.0.15 for osx10.12 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`

```
bin/rails s
Sorry, you can't use byebug without Readline. To solve this, you need 
to rebuild Ruby with Readline support. If using Ubuntu, try `sudo apt-get
install libreadline-dev` and then reinstall your Ruby.
Traceback (most recent call last):
68: from bin/rails:6:in `<main>'
67: from bin/rails:6:in `require'
66: from     

**dlopen(/Users/arthur/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64- 
darwin16/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: 
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: 
/Users/arthur/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64- 
darwin16/readline.bundle
Reason: image not found - 
/Users/arthur/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64- 
darwin16/readline.bundle**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed problem.

Added 'rb-readline' gem file & bundle install.

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/289